# \ref{} does not work under certain circumstances

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

So I know that the problem is at

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

But I don't know if there is a fix to this (without deleting this line, since I don't want numbered sections), since the link in ToC is fine. Basically the effect I want is to have a clickable link on one arbitrary word I write (just like the URL where the link is behind the text).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Test}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
There should be a clickable link: \ref{sec:test}\\
But this works:
\autoref{sec:test}\\
And this also works:
\pageref{sec:test}\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\ref` will return the *number* of the link, and you've removed that by using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. So, your choices are `\nameref{<label>}` or `\hyperlink[<label>]{<text>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
There should be a clickable link: \nameref{sec:test} or \hyperref[sec:test]{TEST} \par
But this works: \autoref{sec:test} \par
And this also works: \pageref{sec:test}
\end{document}
```